# Swift: How to change textField text automatically when other textField got filled?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I implement custom cell that has two `UITextFields`. Anytime I fill one of the text field I want the other to react in being filled with converted value.

Tried `didSet` method but it does not seem to the solution

Example:

```
import UIKit

class ConverterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mgdlTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet
    {
        if let value = Double(mgdlTextField.text!){
            let newValue:Double = value / 38.6
            self.mmolTextField.text = "\(newValue)"
        }

    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mmolTextField: UITextField!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.mgdlTextField.delegate = self

    self.mmolTextField.delegate = self

}
```

EDIT:
I tried the code in the answer below and end up with this error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The didSet is not the solution since it will react when you are assigning the mgdlTextField variable with a new UITextField instance.

Instead, you must register your view controller as the delegate of your textfield and implement the following UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
            replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

In this method, just retrieve the value of your textfield and apply the logic your tried before.

```
import UIKit

class ConverterTableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mgdlTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mmolTextField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.mgdlTextField.delegate = self
        self.mmolTextField.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate methods

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

            if textField == self.mgdlTextField {

                if let text = textField.text {
                    if let value = Double(text) {
                        self.mmolTextField.text = "\(value / 38.6)"
                        return
                    }
                }
                self.mmolTextField.text = ""


            } else {

                if let text = textField.text {
                    if let value = Double(text) {
                        self.mgdlTextField.text = "\(value * 38.6)"
                        return
                    }
                }
                self.mgdlTextField.text = ""
            }

        }

        return true
    }
}
```

The dispatch async is here to ensure your value is updated before you actually do the transform.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: added some implementation code

Comment: Hi, thanks. I added your code to the cell implementation but did not change anything in viewController. End up with unwrapping nil - check my question edit

Comment: I had all these ! to please the compiler, but you should definitely add guards to your code to ensure that the content of .text is not nil or empty.

Comment: Could you edit your code snippet so it was working perfectly and I can grab the idea?;)

Comment: I just did, I added a very simple reset of the other textfield if the other textfield was filled with nil

Comment: still crashing in let newValue:Double = Double(value)! / 38.6 line :(

Comment: I've edited the snippet with more guards. Ensure the Double is not initialized with a string that isn't representing a number, otherwise it will return nil and it will crash...

Comment: However, I found one problem - it requires two characters to work, which implies that it shows bad result - for example when you type 12 it shows only first digit, which is 1, converted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94945/discussion-between-dcdc-and-cyril).